# Is it possible (with varying support) to attach a Azure drive to Azure App Service instance?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-disk

I have an ASP.NET page that needs to access a significant amount of disk space as if it were a local RAID array on a server in a datacenter.

Is there any way to take Azure Drive, Azure Disk or similar, and then add it to the virtual machine that the ASP.NET App Service is running on (via the Console, or other administrative shell or interface?)

Is there any way to get it to work, or should I

- Use a standard Azure IaaS hardware running windows (Can I run Windows Nano?)
- Use a template for Azure PaaS/WebApps and install that on the IaaS, then adding the separate disk?

What (which) would make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Azure not support this.

> Applications can read the system drive as controlled by ACLs on the
> drive. Applications cannot write to any location on the system drive,
> as implemented in the sandbox (i.e. even if ACLs allowed writing to a
> location on system drive, the sandbox would restrict it).

Here is the description about [System drive access restriction](http://System%20drive%20access).